# Calculate sum from 1 to 2000 using child process in shared memory in linux

Tags: c, linux

I have a problem that i have to calculate sum from 1 to 2000 using child process. Here is my code:

```
     #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/ipc.h>
    #include <sys/shm.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <sys/wait.h>  /* Needed for the wait function */
    #include <unistd.h>    /* needed for the fork function */
    #include <string.h>    /* needed for the strcat function */
    #define SHMSIZE 27
    int main() {
       int shmid;
       char *shm;
       int tong1=0;
 int tong2=0;
       if(fork() == 0) {
          shmid = shmget(2009, SHMSIZE, 0);
          shm = shmat(shmid, 0, 0);
          int i;

          for(i=0; i<1000; i++) {
            tong1=tong1+i;
          }
          shmdt(shm);
       }
       else {

          shmid = shmget(2009, SHMSIZE, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
          shm = shmat(shmid, 0, 0);
          wait(NULL);
          int j;

          for(j=1000; j<=2000; i++) {
            tong2=tong2+j;
          }
          shmdt(shm);
          shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL);
       }
       int tong=0; tong=tong1+tong2;
printf("Sum is: %d",tong);
       return 0;
    }
```

But when i run the result is: Sum is 499500 Sum is 1501500. Where am i wrong?

Comment: Try debugginf your code - see if you managed to fork vh printing inside the if, print inside the loop, and see what happends.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate sum from 1 to 2000 using child process in linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42597516/calculate-sum-from-1-to-2000-using-child-process-in-linux)

Comment: Why use a loop and multiple processes? That is a single expression using the Gauss-formula.

Answer (score 1):

because in second cycle, you do `i++` instead of `j++`

```
  for(j=1000; j<=2000; i++) { // <== should be j++
    tong2=tong2+j;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a shared memory segment, but you aren't using it for anything! Simply creating a shared memory segment doesn't cause local variables to be shared between processes -- you need to actually read and write to the shared memory.